# Does 語るでもなくて mean "Not worth speaking"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the opening of **Violet Evergarden** there is this verse:

> わたしなんで泣いているんだろう
>
> 心になんて答えたらいい？
>
> 言葉はいつでも語るでもなくて
>
> そこにあるばかりつのるばかり
>
> わたしはあなたに会いたくなる

I'm having trouble understanding 「言葉はいつでも語るでもなくて」: the general meaning it's "Words aren't always spoken", but I don't understand what's the meaning of 「でもなくて」.

I found [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41339/what-is-the-meaning-usage-etc-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/41344#41344) answer with different meanings for「でもない」, I was wondering if this case it's "Not worth...", so "It's not worthwhile to always speak [I guess meaning 'say aloud'] words", but I'm not sure since the translation I saw didn't have that "worth" meaning, which to me sounds quite strong with respect to a simple "Words doesn't always have to be spoken".

I tried asking a Japanese teacher, and she just said something vague about this being a form that negates the sentence, but I don't understand its grammar: would 「語らなくて」 have a different meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 言葉はいつでも語るでもなくて
>
> そこにあるばかりつのるばかり

First of all, the grammar in those two lines. When I saw you say "Words aren't always spoken", I knew I had to mention the grammar.

「言葉」 is the subject (action-taker) of all of the three verbs -- 「語らない」、「ある」 and 「つのる」.

What words do not do: 「語る」

What words do: 「ある」 and 「つのる」

Thus, the two lines are **roughly** saying:

> "Words do not 語る; They just keep on あるing and つのるing out there."

「語るでもなくて」 does not mean "not worth speaking".  It simply means "Words don't speak/talk", which is a major statement.  The 「でもなくて」 part also implies that words do not do anything else that is important.

Though I hate to quote myself, this is exactly what I said in the linked Q&A.

> 2) denying explicitly one thing and also denying implicitly other things as well

So what do words do if they don't speak/talk?  They just keep on existing and gathering out there.

Comment: Thanks! The translations I found online were quite off, then. Since "Words don't speak" it's strange I'm guessing it could be figurative; could it mean words aren't always meaningful?

Comment: @Mauro IMO it’s like “words themselves do not tell a story”(people do) “they simply exist”(waiting for someone to use them)

Comment: If that's the case I'm wondering about `いつも`: considering it and your interpretation I think it would be something like "Words themselves don't always tell a story", which if the implication is "people do" sounds strange.