# What does 今さら言うでもない mean?

Tags: meaning

> カッ──カッ──カッ──
>
> ハイヒールのコルクが大理石の床を打ち鳴らす。
>
> 眼下に座り込む相手の存在を確かめると、彼女は淑やかな所作で横髪をかき上げつつ言った。
>
> 「どうして、こうなってしまったのかしら──なんて。**今さら言うでもないのでしょうか**」
>
> ──相手は、その言葉をさも当然と聞き届ける。
>
> 地下空間を支配する寂莫たる静けさもまた、最期を看取るのに相応しい黙祷めいて。

I understand 今さら to be used when it's too late to say something e.g. in 【今さら言うのもなんだけど」. I think the meaning in context is the same, however what is confusing me a bit is でもないのでしょうか. If I put together what I think she is saying it is something like, "I wonder if it is a bit too late to say something like that," however, I am not sure.

Comment: The でしょうか at the end in combination with the なんて feel somewhat "cynical" (素直じゃない) to me, but it's hard to put a finger on it without more context...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41339/what-is-the-meaning-usage-etc-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84

Comment: I've added a bit more context (lines before and after), but there isn't much more I can add as the scene is short and its not obvious to the reader. The speaker kills the person they are talking to at the end of the scene.

Comment: @shymander Hm, with the added context, it seems less negative at least. More of a quasi-rhetorical "I guess by now we're well beyond wondering how it all came to this?": a way of confirming that the other person agrees that there is no (longer any) need/desire to talk about whatever lead to the current situation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely to me to be a typo for 今さら言う**ま**でもないのでしょうか, in which case the meaning would be something like "by this point perhaps it's not worth mentioning".